# Excel VBA - need to number cells 1-3 or 1-4 then break and do so again depending on corresponding cells

Tags: vba, excel

New to VBA in Excel and hoping for some swift help.

I have an Excel sheet which contains blocks of 3 or 4 questions each, the blocks are in column F.

I need to number these questions 1-3 or 1-4 in column C, so the numbering would start with a '1' in row 2 where the first question is present in column F, then iterate downwards until there is an empty row where one block has ended, and then when the next block begins below, the number inserted into col C starts at 1 again and iterates downwards to the end of this block, and so on and so forth.

The requirement is essentially: 'Enter ascending numbers in column C if there is a line of text in column F, restarting from '1' after every break in col F'

Over-explained? Probably. But please help!

Comment: its hard to cisualize what you mean, could you add an image or something of what you want to achieve

Comment: Hi Goos, how/where do you add images on here? I can't see an option for this.

Answer (score 0):

This can all be done via formulas.

1. In cell `C1` put in the value `1`.
2. In cell `C2`, put in the formula: =IF(F2="","",IF(F1="",1,C1+1))

Then drag it down.

Hope that does the trick!!!

Comment: Hey John Bustos! Thank you for your answer. The thing is, I need this to work as a macros so that when users receive these spreadsheets, they can just run the macros and it will perform this numbering for them (as this is just one part of a large macros which will change a few things about the spreadsheet). Can your formula be used in a Macros?? I don't even know as I am so unfamiliar with using Excel in this way.

Comment: @bcrhamill, The easiest way for a person who doesn't know macros too well is to do the following.... Record a new macro that puts in the formula as above, drags them down for, say 100000 rows (it will be blank where you don't have values anyways), copies column C and then pastes special values. That should do it!

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub qnum()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim startRow As Long, endRow As Long, qCol As Long, nCol As Long
Dim qnum As Long

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
qCol = 6
nCol = 3
startRow = 2

    With ws
        endRow = Cells(Rows.Count, qCol).End(xlUp).Row
            For q = startRow To endRow
                qnum = 1
                Do While Not .Cells(q, qCol) = ""
                    .Cells(q, nCol) = qnum
                    qnum = qnum + 1
                    q = q + 1
                Loop
            Next q
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Barry, when I run this it says 'Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range'. Any ideas? I will try to fix.

Comment: It was my fault, I was using a sheet called 'TEST 1' not 'Sheet1'. Now the code is running, but it is just numbering every line, it is not breaking and restarting from 1 depending on column F. However, I am VERY grateful to you anyway for your assistance. I will keep trying to fix, but thank you thank you for giving me a great start on this.

Comment: Hi bcr - its working for me.  Presumably you are running this on Sheet1, otherwise - on which line is it falling over and what is the value of q when it does?

Comment: Hi Barry, When this runs, it does work but the numbers appear in strange blocks (1-129, 1-29, 1-5, 1-100, 1-40, 1-39) - ie, numbers get written through some line-breaks, but then others are respected and the sequence breaks and restarts, as it should do every time. I will try to fix, but please post some further info if you do have a chance. Thanks again friend

Comment: Hi bcr, I'll be away from my PC for a short while but I'm afraid I don't quite understand your query on first reading.  Could you provide the data you are using perhaps?

Comment: Hi Barry, thanks for getting back to me. Sadly, I don't think I can send/upload anything via this site as I am a new user? Essentially, I have a spreadsheet which, in column F, has blocks of 3 or 4 questions at a time, separated by an empty row. My task is to create a VBA macros which (among other things) numbers these questions 1-3 or 1-4 in column C, so I would end up with many blocks of colF questions, which have 1-3 or 1-4 values in the corresponding cells in colC, so that each question is numbered within each block. Does this make sense? Thank you for your support.

Comment: OK bcr.  At present the test on numbering is Do While Not .Cells(q, qCol) = "".  This means that if, for example, you have a space in a cell it will still number it.  This could be the case if your Question data has been imported? You can either modify the condition or make sure in your Question data that the blank cells are really blank. Worth checking the latter as the next step?

Comment: Also for good measure add this line: '.Columns(nCol).Clear' just after the 'With ws' line.  This will prevent legacy numbers from persisting.